# Как сделать элемент по умолчанию в select

Tags: python, html, django

подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать элемент по умолчанию в select не трогая сам html код? Используя либо css, либо js.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня вот такая форма сделанная через django и мне нужно выбирать продукт передавая туда его id, а не выбирая из всего списка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю иногда такую задачу  через initial первоначальный аргумент позволяет указать начальное значение в форме. Например:

```
 album_form = AlbumForm(initial={'user': self.request.user,'select_field': your_value})
```

Comment: Спасибо, находил подобные решения, но почему-то не получалось.... Поэтому решил просто сделать через Js, когда в шаблон передается id товара, и через js в select`e этот товар выбирается, а сам select скрыл через display: none. Топорно, но для курсача покатит)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.

document.querySelector("#id_product").value = "{{ product.product_id }}";

где id_product - это name select`a
, а {{ product.product_id }} - значение, которое передает views при рендере моего шаблона!
До этого хотел сделать это все через формы, но потратив на это ОЧЕНЬ много времени,пришел к вот такому топорному, но рабочему решению!